# A word to describe the feeling that you are forgetting something?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word (or short phrase) that describes the sinking feeling that one is forgetting something, but but doesn't know what the "something" is?

For example, I'm looking for a word that describes the following feeling: Leaving to go on holiday, and two hours into your journey you feel sure you have left something important at home but just can't think what it is.

Comment: Dejecta memora: The sadness caused by serial senior moments: Origin: a corruption of *disjecta membra* from the Latin scattered fragments ;-)

Comment: Do you mean: 1) Not being able to remember the name of a restaurant you visited a year ago? 2) Leaving to go on holiday, and two hours into your journey you feel sure you have left something important at home but just can't think what it is? 3) Not being able to remember your husband/wife's name? Or not being able to remember where you live? 4) Something else?

Comment: @WS2 - Excellent clarification. I'm looking more for (2) - "Leaving to go on holiday, and two hours into your journey you feel sure you have left something important at home but just can't think what it is"

Comment: @zashu I'm glad I've helped clarify. I don't know that I can help you with a word to describe this. It is something which sometimes happens to me (has done all my life, so it is not due to seniority!). Sometimes it turns out I have forgotten something, other times it doesn't. Whilst one is in a state of uncertainty about it I guess one feels slightly *insecure*.

Comment: I call it feeling like you're forgetting something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would a "nagging feeling" or "lingering doubt" suit your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If it fits your need, you can go for [disremember](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disremember).

Or even the phrase [fail to recall](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/failed+to+recall) might work great depending on your context.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a feeling of [annoyance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Annoyance):

> - the psychological state of being irritated or annoyed

or a sense of temporary [frustration:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frustration)

> - a feeling of dissatisfaction resulting from unfulfilled needs or unresolved problems.

Access to information is now founded on "random axes", like the Wikipedia site. We're all quite familiar with the [sense of frustration](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZxdQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sense%20of%20frustration%22&dq=%22sense%20of%20frustration%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=N_PiVM7NLdXvaPvrgLgG&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw) we feel when we look for something that won't come to mind, and the sense of relief ensured by search engines ...

(TFD)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I'm looking for something more focused on the _forgetting_ aspect... assuming such a word even exists ;)

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me every single time I go somewhere or I leave, I have this crushing feeling in my chest that I have forgot something really important, even if I check the place I still have it.I made a research and I found a little connection with HYPER VIGILANCE...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Do you have any research and reference that can support your answer? It would be better if you could include them. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Please write an answer when you choose to answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes one speaks of a ***senior moment***, as defined [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=senior+moments)

> a temporary mental lapse (humorously attributed to the gradual loss of
>   one's mental faculties as one grows older).

Example:  "Oops, I think I forgot to lock the back door.  Senior moment!"

Or, more to the OP: "I know I forgot something.  My slippers? the Swiss army knife?  My hair dryer? Too many senior moments lately!"

This phrase does not yet need a euphemism, but better not to use in the company of someone who really does have dementia, or their caregiver.