# A word for a person who feels that he has forgotten something

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word or phrase to describe a person who always feels rthat he has forgotten something even if he hasn't forgotten something really, while going out from somewhere? Example :-

> Peter is a `xxx` as he always feels that he has forgotten something, whenever he goes out of his house.

What can be the replacement of `xxx`?

Comment: "Parent", perhaps?

Comment: "Absent-minded" maybe?

Comment: I doubt there is such a ready-made word or phrase. You are asking for someone to be forgetful but always be aware of being forgetful - and for there to be an expression describing such a person.

Comment: Related: [A word to describe the feeling that you are forgetting something](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227950/a-word-to-describe-the-feeling-that-you-are-forgetting-something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peter is an ***[athazagoraphobe](http://phobiapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Athazagoraphobia)***:

> Fear of being forgotten or ignored or *forgetting*.

Comment: This is maybe the closest, so far, to what the OP asks for (who knows what was really meant), as it makes clear that the person is aware of the possibility (if not the certainty) of forgetfulness.

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted!!! +1 and `accept`.

Answer (score 7):

I'd call such a person  [**absent minded**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absentminded) or perhaps a **[scatterbrain](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatterbrain)** if you need a noun.

"Peter is such a scatterbrain, he forgot his keys again this morning."

"Peter is so absent-minded, he forgot his keys again this morning."

Comment: No. An absent-minded person does **not** necessarily *always thinks that he has forgotten something*. In fact, an absent-minded person might not even be aware that s?he is forgetful (absent-minded).

Comment: @Drew, I am not saying that absent-minded means only this and nothing else. The phrase could mean someone who is unaware of their forgetfulness, but it also might not. The fact that the phrase could have another meaning does NOT make it incorrect.

Comment: Please reread the question. The **question** asks for what I quoted: "*a person who* ***always thinks*** *that he has forgotten something*".

Comment: Please re-read my comment. A person who *always thinks" he has forgotten something could be called absent-minded. This does not mean that every person who is absent-minded must always think that. Unless you're being pedantic, there is no reason to infer that the OP literally means that absolutely every time, with never an exception, the person always believes he has forgotten something. If that's what the poster meant, he could perhaps clear this up for us, but assuming yours is the only correct interpretation is premature.

Comment: Such a person might be called plenty of things, and many of them might apply. That doesn't mean that any of those plenty of things *mean* someone who *always thinks*...

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! But I wanted a word to describe a person who feels that he has forgotten something, but it's not necessary that he really has forgotten something in reality. Maybe my question was unclear and it led to misunderstanding of what I wanted. +1 because you tried to help me!!! Thank You again!!!

Comment: As @Drew suggests, we've got no reason to believe that Peter has ever, in fact, forgotten his keys. An absent-minded person almost certainly has.

Answer (score 2):

> Peter is the **anxious** type. He always feels that he has forgotten something, whenever he goes out of his house.

**anxious**: full of mental distress or uneasiness because of fear of danger or misfortune ([Random-House Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anxious))

Comment: Please explain in your own words why you think this is an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the typical symtoms that an [OCD: Obsessive-compulsive disorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) person/patient shows.

There is no single word in English to describe such thing as it is not normal. Absent-minded or forgetful, etc. cannot pin-point the symtom.

You have to say, He has Obsessive-compulsive disorder.

Obsessive–compulsive disorder (OCD) is a mental disorder **where people feel the need to check things repeatedly, have certain thoughts repeatedly,** or feel they need to perform certain routines repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not an exciting word, but just use "forgetful."

"Bob is a forgetful person."

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forgetful

Comment: No. A forgetful person does **not** necessarily *always thinks that he has forgotten something*. In fact, a forgetful person might not even be aware that s?he is forgetful.

Comment: @Drew fair enough (maybe). Post your own solution.

Comment: I already posted a comment saying that I'm unaware of such an expression, and I doubt that there is one. But if someone comes up with one, we will all learn something. ;-)

Comment: @Drew forgetful people can be aware that they forget things.  Also, someone who is absentminded can be aware of this condition in themselves.  What you are saying in general is that people who have a condition are not self aware.

Comment: **Can be** does not equal **always** is ("*always thinks that he has forgotten...*". No, I am **not** saying that forgetful people are generally not self aware. I am saying that it is not the case that forgetful people are always aware of being so. You have it backwards.

Comment: @Drew, the point is, there's no requirement that the word or phrase must always have exactly this meaning, and must never have any other meaning. Such a requirement is silly and ridiculous.

Comment: Please reread the question. The **question** stipulates such a "silly and ridiculous" requirement: "*a person who* ***always thinks*** *that he has forgotten something*.

Comment: @Drew I know what you mean...unfortunately the OP has put this limitation on us...forgetful, I feel, can handle this...absentminded can also.

Comment: @Drew do you have some alternative suggestion?  If not, that doesn't mean your criticism is invalid but you should have a counterpoint.

Comment: If I say "I'm always losing my keys" any reasonable person will recognize that I do not literally mean that at every moment in time, my keys are constantly in a state of becoming lost. It's very obvious that what I really mean is "frequently" or "commonly" in such a context.

Comment: @barbecue I dunno...I think forgetful covers this...absentminded, as well.

Comment: @Drew, my silly and ridiculous statement was in reference to the artificially introduced requirement that the OP's request was for a word or phrase which has exactly that meaning, and no other meaning. THAT is silly and ridiculous.

Comment: @barbecue: Doesn't matter whether the awareness is always or merely often. The question (as posed) is about being **aware** of it. And that awareness is not implied by *forgetful* (or *absent-minded*). And yes, my comment to the question says, like your "*silly and ridiculous*", that it is doubtful that there is such a ready-made expression. But such comments do not answer the question.

Comment: Did you mean "misplaced......"

Answer (score 0):

I would say *absent-minded* is most apt but *paranoid* would be suitable as well.