# A word for a feeling of having forgotten something?

Tags: single-word-requests, german

Is there any word or phrase to describe that nagging feeling you get when feels like you have forgotten something?

Edit : German words are welcome too! 
Edie Edit : i see [this question has been asked here before, but](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227950/a-word-to-describe-the-feeling-that-you-are-forgetting-something) i dont find any of  the answers satisfactory, i m moving this to German SE

Comment: Was the German word from Big Bang theory in usage in English? It can easily be absolved into English.

Comment: Pretty sure this question's been asked before (but too lazy to look it up).

Comment: @JEL The question looked so familiar. That's why...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you correctly, the idiom **the back of one's mind** could work:

> Used to express that something is in one’s mind but is not consciously thought of or remembered
>   *she had a little nagging worry at the back of her mind*

([www.oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/the-back-of-one%27s-mind))

> ...it is only a **nagging worry at the back of my mind**, like something **I know I should remember** but have forgotten to do, and even that fades to nothingness.

([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ikxFttCWYXMC&pg=PT185&lpg=PT185&dq=Ive%20a%20nagging%20worry%20at%20the%20back%20of%20my%20mind%20that%20Ive%20forgotten%20something.&source=bl&ots=AFmUYq6yYz&sig=GzXp2WDPWzoiPmtwkRC97R98Ais&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI-aORsImXyQIVBxFyCh3eNgSC#v=onepage&q&f=false))

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***draw a blank***

> Fail to find or remember something, as in *He looks familiar but I've
>   drawn a blank on his name*. This expression alludes to drawing a
>   lottery ticket with nothing on it (so one cannot win a prize). [Early
>   1800s] [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/draw+a+blank)